# Is there a way to make a Button alter a ToggleButton's state?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on a Tuner app in Android Studio.

I want to have a button that displays "Start Tuning" & when you click it, the ToggleButton above (which has the image of a mic on & mic off) switches from the Muted Mic image to the Unmuted to show that the app is "listening".

As of right now, I have a button that onClick changes the text view from off to on, however there is no way to go back from on to off, and so far I have found no way to make the mic "button" change as well. Is there a way to do this? Here is the Java code I have so far:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beginTuning = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    mic = findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
    mic_status = findViewById(R.id.micState);
    mic_status.setText("Mic off");
    tester = findViewById(R.id.test_button);

    tester.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (tester.isPressed() && mic.isChecked()) {
                mic_status.setText("on");
            } else {
                mic_status.setText("off");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have stored mute status in variable 'mic' so when volume is turned on' set mute-check-status to 'false': You just need to **add statements marked 1.. and 2.. to your code;**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            if (tester.isPressed() && mic.isChecked()) {
                mic_status.setText("on");
                mic.setChecked(false);            // 1..add just this line so 'else' part of condition will execute next time

            } else {
                mic_status.setText("off");
                mic.setChecked(ture);   // 2..also  set mute checked..
            }
        }
    });
```